# PHP One time database query on application startup

Tags: php, caching

I have a ajax based PHP app (without any frameworks etc.).

I need to retrieve some records from the database (html select element items) ONCE, and once only, during application startup, store it in a PHP array, and have this array available for future use to prevent future database calls, for ALL future users.

I could do this easily in Spring with initializing beans. And this bean would have the application scope (context) so that it could be used for ALL future user threads needing the data. That means the database retrieval would be once, only during app boot, and then some bean would hold the dropdown data permanently.

I can't understand how to replicate the usecase in PHP.

There's no "application" bootstrapping as such, not until the first user actually does something to invoke my php files.

Moreover, there is no application context - records retrieved for the first user will not be available to another user.

How do I solve this problem? (Note: I don't want to use any library like memcache or whatever.)

Comment: I'm confused by this question. If you're pulling static data and want to use it for everyone, why are you using a database?

Comment: Without memcache I'm not sure if there IS a way...

Comment: PHP is a scripting language, every time someone requests a page that counts as an application startup and when the script ends, the application ends.

Comment: @MetalFrog It's incorrect to assume that the data is of static nature. I'm not talking about a dropdown of USA states, or planets in the solar system etc.

Consider a dropdown of disease names and their codes. A department may increase that key value pair based on business conditions - reason good enough to put it in a database. However, they may not add/remove very frequently - that's reason good enough to retrieve it once on app boot, and not again and again from the database.

Comment: Are we talking hundreds of pairs, thousands, tens or hundreds of thousands?  @Catfish may have the better solution if you *must* only query on occasion - create a template with a script on a schedule, like nightly, and then serve up the template.

Comment: Done. Scheduled it to update weekly, Sunday midnight, local time. Cached to xml. Now I have TRUE application context caching! What's with all the fuss around memcache and APC etc? This was easy as pie. Thanks for all the suggestions though.

Answer (score 3):

If you truly need to get the data only the first time the app is loaded by any user, than you could write something that gets the data from your database, and then rewrites the html page that you're wanting those values in. That way when the next user comes along, they are viewing a static page that has been written by a program.

I'm not so sure that 1 call to the database everytime a user hits your app is going to kill you though. Maybe you've got a good reason, but avoiding the database all but 1 time seems rediculous IMO.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hit the database one time per visitor, you could use $_SESSION.  At the beginning of your script(s) you would start up a session and check to see if there are values in it from the database.  If not, it's the user's first visit and you need to query the database.  Store the database values in the $_SESSION superglobal and carry on.  If the data is in the session, use it and don't query the database.

Would that cover you?

Comment: Yep, almost forgot that! That solves 60% of the problem. Now, the challenge is to figure out how to do it at the application level, once and once only. Basically for the first user to invoke the php script, and not ever after. Java/J2EE has this covered so well. Anyways, what you have suggested is what I'm doing now.

Comment: If you just need to do this very occasionally, you could output the data you need into a flat text file and read it with the script, but a database query may be a lot faster.  Where does this singleton query requirement come from?  A database may not be the solution you need.